# luma : Depends: python-qt3 (>= 3.11) but it is not installable

Tags: python, pip, raspberry-pi, apt

I am currently trying with:

```
apt install luma
```

but unfortunately I get the following error message:

```
 luma : Depends: python-qt3 (>= 3.11) but it is not installable
```

however, I already have the new version on the server.

```
python-qt4 is already the newest version (4.12.1+dfsg-2+b2).
```

and still I can't install "luma". Does somebody has any idea??? I've already tried with pip. without success...

Comment: From error it looks like you will need to install the `python-qt3` to get it working. Have you tried that?

Comment: yes i did. What I get was this of course:```E: Package 'python-qt3' has no installation candidate```

Comment: python-qt3 is outdated and has been replaced by python-qt4.

Comment: http://luma.sourceforge.net/requirements.html

Comment: all right. damned. Well I have to install the old version python-qt3. Thank you....